# Unable to view images on my website

Tags: web-services

Sorry for the vague title but:

I can't seem to view images, that I can see listed on fileZilla, on my website. I try to access them directly (eg. site.com/images/photo.jpg) but then I get a message from the browser saying that it doesn't exist. When use the file manager from cpanel, it is still listed/existing.

The site works well on my computer. I just don't get it :s

Thank you for your help in advance :D

Comment: It's possible your browser cached that fact that it is missing. I've had Chrome cache 404 page until I refresh so if you visited the image before it was there and then next time I guess it's possible it might assume its still not. However more likely your URL is typed wrong or it's possible the server is restricting it. Triple check your URL and clear your cache.

Comment: 1: are you using relative or absolute urls.

Comment: Yes about the cache, I cleared it, the URL is definitely correct. The situation seems pretty ridiculous... Extention is also correct, its .jpg

Comment: @Matt.C, what do you mean?

Comment: Please see my answer below, I actually believe that this is the most likely answer having re-read your question.

Comment: Are you able to access non-image files?  For example, try uploading a text file alongside the images and access it via `site.com/images/myfile.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say the site is working on YOUR computer,

Check the letter casing (eg capital letters in file and path names) of your image and paths, linux based web hosting is case sensitive. windows filenames are not.

Comment: Yes yes, you nailed the exact problem. The problem was with the extension. Apparently .JPG doesn't mean .jpg

Comment: They do mean the same thing, and on Windows this is fine, however linux based files systems are case sensitive, so as far as the web server is concenered it couldn't find the image. if you look at the logs or browser console you'll probably see it as a 404